# Late binding of .net CLR in VBA (Access)

Tags: .net, vba, ms-access

In the follow post it shows how one can use VBA, create a instance of the CLR and thus call/use/consume .net COM objects without having to register such objects.

[Side-By-Side COM Interop with C# and VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1903220/side-by-side-com-interop-with-c-sharp-and-vba/13333819#13333819)

I looking to replace this code:

```
Dim Host As mscoree.CorRuntimeHost
Set Host = New CorRuntimeHost
```

With

```
Set Host = createObject("mscoree.CorRunTimeHost")
```

I am unable to find the "class" name.

In other words, I want to late bind the CLR. Does anyone know if it is possible to use VBA CreateObject() in place of the having a hard reference from VBA to the above mscore

The “reference” set in VBA - > tools is

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\mscoree.tlb
```

In effect I looking to late bind use of the .net CLR via CreateObject()

Comment: Isn't the class name `CorRuntimeHost`? Does `CreateObject("mscoree.CorRunTimeHost")` give you a `Host` set to `Nothing`?

Comment: My guess is that it can't be done without adding a COM reference to the typelib in the registry.  If I call `Debug.Print TypeName(Host)`, it reports `Unknown`.

Comment: A good crack on this on your part - I believe you are correct - without a typelib in the registry - I cannot late bind. However, it MIGHT be possible if the mscoree.tlb was not managed code!

Answer (score 1):

I believe you may need to register the typelib first (can't confirm ATM because I used regtlibv12.exe to register it before I went hunting for the class name). The class name appears to be "CLRMetaData.CorRunTimeHost".

Comment: Appreciate the class name - unfortunately CreateObject still does not work - I MUCH agree and suspect you are correct - the issue is such a object needs a regasm /codebase to work. Of course avoiding the need to register anything on locked down machines is very much the reason for this post. Funny that a reference set in Access VBA works, but allowing CreateObject does not.